# App installation failed when transfered code

Tags: android, android-studio

So i started my project on Mac OS and than with USB i transfered to MacOS, using same version of Android studio, but on Mac it doesn't want to run i tried to delte gradle and idea folders build a gradle and all but no success. The error i get is Application Installation Failed:

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: /Users/myuser/Code/App/E:\Android\apps\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
>
> Do you want to uninstall this existing application?

So as it looks like its picking up my Windows things from somewhere any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Try disabling Instant Run.

Comment: Remove the existing app with the same package name.
Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Disable the Instant Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just run: ./gradlew clean and disabled instant run and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just `Clean` & `Rebuild` the project.